# After doing TOA correction to a lansat 8 image band using raster calculator, the reflectance is slightly out of range. Why is that so?

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat-8, toa-calibration

[image: TOA correction]the reflectance range was like for example 0.0023 to -1.02356 for some band and -0.0156 to 0.009. Why is this reflectance range slightly out of range? Isn't it should be in exactly in between 0 to 1. If so what can we do to correct this?
[image: this is the image showing how i did TOA correction and the result of it]

Comment: I suspect that you may well have made an error in your correction -  can you specify exactly how you did your correction?

Comment: 1)First i set projection to WGS84                                                                2)then i added all bands of landsat 8 image of my study area                      3)then i started applying TOA correction following the lansat 8 guide from raster calculator                                                                                   4)the formula i used is as:ρλ' = MρQcal + Aρ 
5)After that it was divided by Sin(solar elevation)

Comment: 6)And i did this correction for every bands except panchromatic abd TIRS bands. 7) the resulting raster was supposed to be in the range 0-1 exactly but in my case it didn't happen. 8) then i had to apply streching(i used DRA option), then only the range adjusted to somewhat near the 0-1 range but still not perfectly.

Comment: @MikkelLydholmRasmussen i have attached the snapshot of my work. So, can you please correct my work and what iam missing here

Comment: you are multiplying by something other than the gain. The gain is usually 0.00002 and not 0.00005.

Comment: @MikkelLydholmRasmussen Sorry that was a typo, i have put 0.00002 in the formula now and its the same

Comment: what are the actual values in the image? What values are you seeing in the brightest actual parts of the map? It often happens that the min and max values are rather wrong.

Comment: @MikkelLydholmRasmussen In the image the mountain peaks with snow have reflectance values like for example 1.05, but other land areas have reflectance values like 0.14, water  bodies have reflectance like 0.16, 0.15 for band 1. So is it okay to use these pixel reflectance values for analysis? Can you suggest me some papers that discuss this problem if you know any.         .

Comment: you get values above 1 because of the solar elevation correction. I don't think that it is applicable anymore. Beyond that, the fact that QGis provides wrong values is a technical issue that has no effect on your actual analysis.

Comment: @MikkelLydholmRasmussen sir, also one more thing, when i apply stretching ( DRA ) in image analysis then the range adjusts within the 0-1 range. Again is it okay to use stretching if i have to use pixel reflectance value for statistical analysis? Sorry to bother you sir, but this doubt has been quite a roadblock for my study.

Comment: if you don't apply the solar elevation correction, then you don't have any values outside the range of 0 and 1, in which case you can proceed with your analysis.

Comment: @MikkelLydholmRasmussen Thank you very much sir. It really helped.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using the the  [Semi automatic classification plugin](http://semiautomaticclassificationmanual-v3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Tutorials.html) of QGIS and I haven't had that problem. The plugin has a module for TOA correction.See the [documentation](http://semiautomaticclassificationmanual-v3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: ok i'll try this option